# When are text field lengths enforced in Salesforce? Can I get the actual field length?

Tags: api, salesforce, bulkinsert

I was importing data from Salesforce today, when my BULK INSERT failed with too-long data: longer than the field length as reported from Salesforce itself.  I discovered that this field, which Salesforce describes as a `TEXT(40)`, has values up to 255 characters long.  I can only guess that the field *had* a 255-character limit in the past, was changed to `TEXT(40)`, and Salesforce has not yet applied the new limit.

When are field lengths enforced?  Only when new data is inserted or modified?  Are they enforced at any other point, such as a weekly schedule?

Second, is there any way to know the *actual* field length limit?  As a database guy, not being able to rely on the metadata I've been given makes me cringe.  As just one random example, if we were to restore this table from backup I assume that the long values would bomb, or possibly be truncated.

I'm using the SOAP API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Field lengths are enforced on create/update. If you later reduce the length, existing records are not truncated. I imagine this is because salesforce is storing these as 255's regardless.

Pragmatically speaking, the "actual" field limit for any text field in salesforce should be considered 255. This is because it's possible that at some point in the past, records were inserted when the limit was as high as 255.

And you're right that if you were to dump that table and re-insert it, you very well could have rejected records due to values that exceed the field size as currently defined.

Comment: No hidden "previous field length" field?  Oh well, it was a long shot.  This gives me what I need, thank you, Mr. Ross!